# Help with changing the operating system

Tags: windows, dell

please I am new in this Forum and in this, I want to download the Ubuntu OS and change the Windows starter I already have in the Dell laptop. Is it that possible?
How can I do it?
Any help?
Please
 Really appreciate.

Comment: It is absolutely possible, but much depends on what you wish to keep and what you wish to get rid of.  Will you need to back up anything? I recommend you start [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and get and make an install DVD and then follow the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). I happen to prefer the LTS "Long Term Service" version of Ubuntu, but 15.10 is also a good choice. You may need to find some particular drivers for your system; but in general, installing Ubuntu should be about as easy as installing Windows 95 was.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am COMPLETELY new on this and I need it for my son. The thing is his Dell (mini) is running VERY slow and actually he can't even do anything without taking a long time. This is why we want to change the OS so that we can try something different that might work better.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

After you download it, insert a blank DVD into your computer. Choose to do nothing when the AutoPlay (or similar) dialog pops up. Right click the .iso file and choose "Burn to disk". (That should be close to the actual wording.) Once that is done, put/keep the disk in and restart your computer. After that, go here and follow the instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
You need to first download the iso file, then the easiest way for beginner in my opinion is to burn that Ubuntu iso file to a DVD. (make sure your system architecture is the same as the iso. eg. If your machine is 64bit, then download the 64bit Ubuntu and so on). Once you have done that, you have to insert the disk, restart your computer, and go onto your BIOS setting (spamming F2 on my dell laptop while it's booting up, yours might be F12, F10, or F8 depending on your machine). Go to a boot device sequence settings and you should change the boot priority to your DVD/USB that you have burn your iso file into. From there, it will start booting from that device, and will ask if you want to install Ubuntu to replace the OS, or install it side by side (dual booting). I have mine dual booted, so I can switch around between Ubuntu and Windows. From there, the rest of the installation process is pretty much self-explanatory. Partitioning, settings, etc. Good luck, and if you have any questions or my instruction is unclear, just reply. (I'm rushing this answer)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your quick answer..But i'm afraid I have to wait till tomorrow to buy a DVD..  :(

Answer (score 0):

First download ubuntu os 64 bit or 32 bit depending on your computer.Then you need to make a bootable usb/cd drive,you can easily do that with http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/.
Then reboot your system with your usb/cd in and press F12.In BIOS menu select BOOT--->Hard Disk Drives.Next follow the installation of ubuntu ;)